# Find element in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a table:

```
    Name1   Name2           Name3
0     ABC     FGD             NNY
1  ABSTRE      PC  ABSTRE Tree in
2       P  ABSTRE             NNY
3     JJJ     FGD             NNY
4  ABSFRE      PC          ABSKRE
```

I need get these info:

```
['ABSTRE', 'ABSFRE', 'ABSTRE', 'ABSKRE']
```

So its means that code has the same 3 letters and the same length.

- The same 3 letters: ABS
- Length: 6

I need get all codes from table. I think it should be something like these:

```
t='^[A-Z0-9]{3,10}?$'
for i in df.items():
    l=df[df[i].str.contains(t)]
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Is `ABC` correct ? It is not typo and need `ABS` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need extract codes with 3 and 6 lengths:

```
print (df)
    Name1   Name2           Name3
0     ABS     FGD             NNY <- changed ABC to ABS
1  ABSTRE      PC  ABSTRE Tree in
2       P  ABSTRE             NNY
3     JJJ     FGD             NNY
4  ABSFRE      PC          ABSKRE
```

---

```
t1 = '^([A-Z0-9]{3})?$'
t2 = '^([A-Z0-9]{6})?$'

s = df.filter(like='Name').stack()

s1 = s.str.extract(t1, expand=False).dropna()
print (s1)
0  Name1    ABS
   Name2    FGD
   Name3    NNY
2  Name3    NNY
3  Name1    JJJ
   Name2    FGD
   Name3    NNY
dtype: object

s2 = s.str.extract(t2, expand=False).dropna()
print (s2)
1  Name1    ABSTRE
2  Name2    ABSTRE
4  Name1    ABSFRE
   Name3    ABSKRE
dtype: object
```

And then filter second `Series s2` by first 3 values and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = s2[s2.str[:3].isin(s1)].tolist()
print (L)
['ABSTRE', 'ABSTRE', 'ABSFRE', 'ABSKRE']
```

If want check by all substrings:

```
pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(s1))
L = s2[s2.str.contains(pat)].tolist()
print (L)
['ABSTRE', 'ABSTRE', 'ABSFRE', 'ABSKRE']
```

If want extract all values starting by `ABC` with length `6` use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
t = "^(ABS[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})$"
L = df.filter(like='Name').stack().str.extract(t, expand=False).dropna().tolist()
print (L)

['ABSTRE', 'ABSTRE', 'ABSFRE', 'ABSKRE']
```

or another @Shaido answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the "ABS" letters are always in the beginning of the word, you can do the following:

```
df = df.stack()
values = df.loc[df.str.contains("^ABS[0-9a-zA-Z]{3}$")].tolist()
```

This will match all words of length 6 that starts with "ABS". Result of `print(values)`:

```
['ABSTRE', 'ABSTRE', 'ABSFRE', 'ABSKRE']
```